# Use a compiled dart executable as DynamicLibrary in Flutter

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, dart-ffi

Since a longer time now it is possible to open a DynamicLibrary (dylib, dll, so) in Flutter. Those libraries are written in C or C++.

I've now tried to build a basic dart command line application, compiled it using `dart compile exe` and tried to load it in my Flutter application using `DynamicLibrary.open()`, as you would do with the native libraries in C/C++.

```
typedef HelloWorldFunc = Void Function();
typedef HelloWorld = void Function();

...

final dynLib = DynamicLibrary.open('/path/to/cli.exe');
final HelloWorld func = dynLib.lookup<NativeFunction<HelloWorldFunc>>('hello_world').asFunction();
func();
```

(I've followed this tutorial and just added an empty void function called hello_world
https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/get-started#3-create-a-small-app)

But the symbol could not be found:

```
Failed to lookup symbol 'hello_world': dlsym(0x7fec2310e5a0, hello_world): symbol not found
```

**Question**

Is it generally possible to open dart-compiled libraries in Flutter, like DLLs written in C++? Since `dart compile exe`  generates native machine code as well

If yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: An `exe` isn't a shared object / dll - so it's not going to export methods in the way a dll does. If you want to call Dart code from Dart code you'd want to put it in a package and `import` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart cannot create shared libraries like other languages can do because it needs to be run in an embedder/DartVM.

This issue has a good explanation:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37480